# Cheap Space travel

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, spaceships

A disclaimer: There is a lot of real Science involved.

Imagine a world which is exactly a copy of Earth (at least in terms of power as a species and technology). There is a company that aims to make space travel extremely cheap so that Earth could actually import stuff from asteroids passing by (just to give you a financial estimate). For reasons of abstraction, a method of converting electrical energy directly into kinetic linear motion (unlike a motor, which is rotational) has already been discovered.

My question is about the feasibility of making a "spaceship" whose only operational cost is in energy (everything else is, like in real life, considerably cheaper). There are two facets to this problem that I could see:

1. Can we claim back most (in the order of 95%) of the energy of the ship that is falling back to Earth as part of Law of Conservation of Energy, assuming that Second Law of Thermodynamics (100% efficiency is not possible) still applies?
2. Even then, energy is lost through air resistance. Is there an theoretical substance which could be mass produced (it maybe be slightly expensive), could work in rough conditions and still provide zero (or near zero) air resistance regardless of speed of the spaceship? The shape of the ship till be as aerodynamic as possible.

**This part may help, but it is not necessary to look into:** It may be possible that the ship is fired from a spaceport using electricity and a falling ship could be caught by the spaceport to convert its kinetic energy into electricity using, say super-capacitors to store the energy (because they charge really fast).

Comment: Are you asking how to make the operational costs net 0, or the launch energy costs net 0? (Or as close as possible). Those are two different questions; one involves manufacturing, labor, personnel, etc and the other physics and energy.

Comment: [Space elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) can save you.

Comment: We actually have *"a method of converting electrical energy directly into kinetic linear motion"*; it's called a [linear motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motor), and is used in various applications such as [coilguns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coilgun) and [rapid transit systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_motor#Train_propulsion). As for the *"theoritical substance which could [...] provide zero (or near zero) air resistance"*, you understand that "air resistance" has nothing to do with friction and is strictly a function of the *shape* and *speed* of the airfoil?

Comment: I have a feeling this is more of a physics question than a world building one, read up on what energy is before you go there though, your use of the term energy is way too broad.

Comment: There are a bunch of (more or less wacky looking) [non-rocket launch platforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-rocket_spacelaunch) that might fit.

Comment: @Christian total energy cost near zero for the launch only. Everything else is neglected.

Comment: @Alexander I mean a space elevator maybe an option, but it is too dangerous and costly isn't it? Also, can a civilzation like Earth's can't make one.

Comment: @AlexP So what you are saying is, air resistance is not linked to the interface between the gas and the substance the ship is made out of? I think you are mistaken: this [link] (http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/air_resistance_formula/85/) shows that the air resistance is indeed linked to the drag coefficient, which is dependent upon the interaction between both the gas and the substance.

Comment: @Kavi Vaidya - we need some sort of structure for ascending and descending, if we want effective energy conversion and recapture. If you mean that spaceships should use some "reactionless" electric engine for launch and landing, that's too unscientific.

Comment: @V. Sim It is not strictly physics because this is hypothetical and is more pseudoscience. Over here, energy is something that the civilization could use to power its space ship or anything else. Also, physics does not deal wth financial feasability.

Comment: @Alexander So the last part is just a suggestion to get people involved. If that is too unscientific, any other means may suffice. The goal is to allow as little energy disipation as possible.

For example (again, you do not have to follow, but I am just suggesting): hydrogen/oxygen combustion to launch and the recovered energy gained by catching the spaceship is used to make more hydrogen from water. This does have problems though because AFAIK hydrogen combustion is only about 50 percent efficient.

Also, maybe a very tall launch tower may also suffice.

Comment: The drag coefficient is dependent on the *shape* of the surface (both its gross shape and its smoothness or roughness); it does not matter what substance the airfoil is made of.

Comment: @AlexP You are correct and I think I should edit my question. But before I do that, does this sound more scientifically feasible: a design or substance that makes as close to zero air resistance regardless of the speed of the ship.

Comment: @KaviVaidya [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics))(air/fluid resistance) is defined as a force acting against the relative motion of an object with respect to the fluid it is surrounded by... motion cannot be ignored if its part of the definition

Comment: @V.Sim you mean the "regardless of speed" what I mean is that even in high speeds, the air resistance and drag should be near zero.

Comment: in that case either the fluid density has to be really really low, or the cross section of the object striking the fluid has to be really really low,

Comment: After thinking a lot about this, I've decided to vote to close.  You're asking 3 questions when you're only supposed to be asking 1 and the questions are very opinion based.  I could have picked "Primarily Opinion-Based" but I elected to choose "too broad."  Frankly, it doesn't matter which.  (a) There are nowhere near enough conditions to allow for one right answer.  It's OK to fish for ideas so long as one best answer can be determined.  As written, no answer is any better than any other.  (b) Ask one question.

Comment: I tried to edit this question to clarify it and failed.  What, really, are you asking about?  The feasibility of a low-cost operation?  How to make it a low-cost operation?  How to recover energy to minimize energy cost?  Please do not answer as a comment.  Please edit your question to be a single, clear question.

Comment: Your core question is about the feasibility of space travel using a technology that converts electricity directly into kinetic energy. For spaceships landing, on Earth or any planet, they will convert electricity into kinetic energy again, but in the opposite direction to the spaceship's motion. Thereby, decelerating it so it can land. The answers to your two facets are no and no. They are non-problems with this type of space propulsion technology.

Comment: space elevator is the only practical technollogy capable of reasonable efficiency,  wings are horribly inefficient.  could we build a bridgehead in space today?  yeah probably. It would be expensive lifting enough mass to geosynchronous orbit to lay the first cable.  another hard part  would be keeping terrorists away from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NASA is working on an EM drive that uses the pressure of microwaves to move forward.  If that works at all, it won't produce a lot of thrust.

What you describe is like the hand waved Star Trek "Impulse Engines."  If you posit that then your drive works.  If you don't want to hand wave it that much, you are out of luck.

In order to convert your downward motion into energy, you would have to have something to act against.

1. A wind turbine mounted on the ship would do it but would only
   capture a small fraction of the energy you are talking about.
2. Impact with the ground transfers all the energy of the drop (less
   wind resistance).  However, you would need a way to convert it into
   a form that is more useful than terrain excavation.  The longer the
   "impact" takes the easier it is to handle the energy.  So landing on
   a long ramp or rails would make the energy easier to handle.

As far as wind resistance is concerned, regardless of shape, the faster you go the more wind resistance you face.  So, to minimize wind resistance, go slow.  Attaching to rails is one way to slow yourself down and regain a great deal of the energy.

Comment: ShadoCat, This addresses the two "facets" (posed as questions), but does not answer the question: "My question is about the feasability of making a spaceship whose only operational cost is in energy."

Comment: @JBH, that's the problem with asking more than one question in a post.  You never know which one will get answered.  In any case, I edited my answer to answer the feasibility question.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm frankly having trouble saving this question.  You did a good job.

Comment: @JBH The two facets of the problem are non-problems. Vide my comment above on the question.

Comment: Well done. You've thought through the aspects of the questions and provided appropriate answers. Plus one.

Comment: "form that is more useful than terrain excavation" I think is really important to note... essentially all the cost of getting a rocket to space is in energy which is why I found it hard to answer this question. I believe they intended to ask how much of the energy required would be recoverable in some readily usable form (electric).

Comment: @V.Sim, yes, the rails would act as a generator on the way down and a linear accelerator on the way up.  It is essentially a space elevator without a car.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an orbital ring. A solid ring of matter that is stationary to the earth, magnetically levitated above an orbiting wire. With cables from it to the ground.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMbI6sk-62E

Using these and magnetic acceleration, you can launch payloads for a reasonable amount of electricity, and regain most of that energy when they return. If you are mining asteroids, this could be net positive in electricity.

Answer (score 1):

By far and large the largest factor that determines the expense of a spaceship is if it is manned or not.

If it is manned, this severely limits your options. The largest expense is that of safety and redundancy. To ensure the safety of the crew, multiple systems require rigorous testing, research must be conducted in risk analysis with no tolerance for any failure. Keep in mind the cost of a launch platform of any kind is a small cost compared to the dozens, if not hundreds, of failures and tests that preceded it.

Add that to of course the weight penalty of life support, communications and control systems, training, health, food, water, waste disposal, insurance and crew amenities - you can easily see why the Space Shuttle became the behemoth it did, and although mostly successful, the program was often considered much too expensive for what it achieved.

Alternatively unmanned ships could be launched with relatively small payloads, on launch vehicles that it would not matter too much if they fail. Space X is an example where the re-use of launch vehicles could reduce launch costs by a third, where the heavy rocket was actually a trio of the same launch vehicle design, however if manned they have reiterated they would need to develop a completely different design for reasons above.

If you want to have costs even less than this, you need to think outside the box and look at methods of launch other than rockets.

1. Forget about 'space elevators' and 'orbiting rings' - the energy, material and construction costs for these mega-structures are well north of any savings you would get from the use of these structures. (A cable from the Lagrange point to earth will need to be 1km thick steel to not snap - think about that for a moment)
2. Mass drivers are an option, essentially making the spacecraft a bullet, but this is definitely not an option if it is to be manned.
3. You could accelerate a solar sail craft using lasers from the ground, however this is not tested at all yet.
4. Space planes are an option but no-one has perfected them - combined with high altitude launches this could be possible and more realistic. However, fuel is a large cost associated with this option, and I know in your question you mentioned conserving energy. The weight penalty for duel propulsion and fuel is a major negative to this route.
5. One option you could consider if you do not want on-board propellant: orbital airships. Using staged airships, it may be possible to slowly but surely lift a light buoyancy craft to the upper atmosphere, then use solar power to slowly accelerate it to orbital velocity, over several days, weeks or even months. JP Aerospace I believe is working on this concept, and although prototypes have been made they haven't got there yet. However, I could easily envisage this to be an ultra-low cost way to orbit with reusable cheap craft. Re-entry would be easier because of its lightweight nature and size.

Getting up to space cheaply is a hot topic at the moment, it's a holy grail and everyone is trying to look at ways to do it. Long gone are the old Nasa days of dumping large amounts of funding, fuel and labour into a program to get something up there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo science is solution that comes from 1960 scifi*

Your ships use a magnetic drive to take off and labs on the earth, only able to land on landing pads that can produce a powerful em field. As the ship lands their kinetic energy is converted into stored energy on  the em landing field.

Really powerful drives don't need a landing pad that boosts the planets em field, but can land anywhere.

*cannot remember who the author is, or the book name. It was from a penny book.